# std::search on single-pass range

Tags: c++, search, iterator, c++17, boyer-moore

I'd like to read from a `std::istream` until a certain sequence of characters is found, i.e., I'd like to implement the following interface:

```
void read_until (std::istream &is, std::string_view needle);
```

Using `std::istreambuf_iterator`, I believe this is equivalent to a combination of `std::search` on a single-pass iterator. Unfortunately, the `std::boyer_moore_searcher` needs random-access iterators.

Are there any easy implementations of the above interface using the C++ standard library (and a bit of memory proportional to the size of `sv`), or do I have to code it myself?

Comment: And where exactly are you reading this data into? Or are you simply going to advance the stream to that point?

Comment: Simply advancing the stream. For example when parsing and I expect a certain keyword next, and I don't want to be very picky and just say "skip everything until you have found that sequence of characters".

Comment: Um, `std::search` works on any forward iterator.  Now, your `istream` iterator isn't a forward iterator, but you don't need random access at least.

Answer (score 1):

```
void read_until (std::istream &is, std::string_view needle) {
  if (needle.size()==0) return;
  std::string buff;
  buff.reserve(needle.size());
  auto it = std::find_if( std::istream_iterator<char>(is), std::istream_iterator<char>(), [&](char c) {
    buff.push_back(c);
    if (buff.size() < needle.size()) {
      return false;
    }
    if (buff == needle)
      return true;
    buff.erase(buff.begin());
    return false;
  });
}
```

that is the best I can do with `std` algorithms.

For optimization, using a circular `buff` might save a bit of work.